# How to develop with git subtree?

Tags: git, branch, subtree

The main problem is that the git subtree doesn't work without squash. Below I have added an example where I have 2 repositories (subtree and repo1).

1. I have added **subtree** repo to **repo1** `git subtree add --prefix subtree subtree_repo main`
2. Added new commit to **subtree** repo
3. Merged new commit from subtree using command `git subtree merge --prefix=subtree subtree_repo/main`
4. Now i can't push to **subtree** repo. Why? You can check branch **temp_branch** = `git subtree split --prefix=subtree HEAD -b temp_branch` and in new commit git subtree trying to move files. Why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is62J.png)

Expecting push to subtree repo without new commits and changes